# JPA+Hibernate force JPA not to use Proxies on Lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy, lazy-loading

We are using JPA + Hibernate.
I have some Many-to-one mappings which are lazy loaded.

In Service, I Initiallize the Many-to-one objects by calling their getter method. but proxy gets assigned to parent VO and not actual VO Object.

My Question is, Is there any way in JPA to force to use no proxy Strategy.
My limitation here is i cant use Hibernate Objects or annotaions like @LazytoOne etc.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent Hibernate from using proxy objects there due to the fact that somehow it has to guarantee it's a lazy relation.

You have multiple choices:

1. Trigger the initialization `Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChild())`. Note that this is not the best way to do it and this also requires an active transaction.
2. Fetch the relation when fetching the entity itself. This can be done with the Fetch Joins. JPQL/HQL/Criteria API are capable of doing this.
3. Use read-only projections which contains only the data you need. For this particular case you can use [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) as it comes with such a feature.

I suggest you to go with either option 2 or 3 as they are the most effective ways to do this.

Furher reading about lazy-loading [here](http://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/2017/02/27/lazyinitializationexception-demystified/).